# How do I JSON_encode a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

```
value = re.findall(b,'some regex',respdata)
keywords = re.findall(b,'some regex',respdata)

#Empty dictionary
Dictionary = {}
x=0
for eachValue in value:
        Dictionary[eachValue] = keyword[x]
        x+=1        
print(Dictionary)
```

After this, I want to JSON encode the Dictionary in "value:keyword" format, any suggestions on how I could do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you seen the [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/) yet?

Answer (score 2):

Python has a module `json`:

```
value = re.findall('some regex',respdata)
keywords = re.findall('some regex',respdata)
print json.dumps(dict(zip(value, keywords)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the stdlib:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(Dictionary))
```

Also, make sure you are following PEP conventions with your variable naming, I believe the capitalization of your dictionary variable here is a violation, see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions

Comment: I'm a newbie in Python. Was trying to get my feet wet with Web Scrapping, I haven't gone through the docs for the Python Standard Library